# Asseration Failed

Tags: c++, opencv

After that I have added the function readcode in my class I got the error 
" C++ Debug Assertion Failed, Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead - nblockUse ) "
when I close the program, what  should I change?

This is code :

timecodeReader.cpp

```
 void TimecodeReader::readcode(Mat& im,int& istart,int & jstart,int d)


 {  


    int k,c,iakk;
   //String //
  code="";
  for(k=0;k<33;k++)
  {
    iakk=istart+k*d;
    c=checkBlock(im,iakk,jstart);
     if(c>245) 
        code=code+"1";
     else 
        code=code+"0";
}
  std::cout << code << std::endl;
//return code;

 }
```

The header file :

```
   #include <cv.h>
   #include <highgui.h>

   #include <String>
   #include <math.h>

 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;

 class TimecodeReader
   {
    public:
TimecodeReader(int newVertPosition = Bottom);
Mat getDrawing();
Mat getBinary();
bool getTimecodePosition(Mat newCapture, double dispIgnore);
int getTimecode(Mat newCapture);
void setContourLimit(int low, int high);
Mat binaryImage;
Mat binaryImageCpy;
Mat drawingImage;

   private:
void setCapture(Mat newCapture);
bool calcArea();
void calcTresholds();
void calcMeans();
bool decodeMeans();
bool checkContours();
//int getDecimal();
Mat calcHistogram(Mat roiCapture);
double calcHistogramMean(Mat newHistogram);
void drawHistogram(Mat newHistogram);


Mat capture;
RNG rng;
Rect roi;
string binary[2];
double decodeDefaultTresholds[2];
int decodeAberration; 
double decodeTresholds[2][2][2];
int contourLowLimit;
int contourHighLimit;
const static int TimecodeCount = 41;
int vertPosition;
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<vector<Point>> contoursSimple;
vector<vector<Point>> contourAreas;
vector<double> means;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    int checkBlock(Mat& img, int& i, int& j);
    int thres(Mat& img,int h,int w);
    bool decision(Mat& im,int h,int w,int j);
    int getdistance(Mat& im,int& i, int& j,int width, int height);
    int getdoubledistance(Mat& im,int& i, int& j,int width, int height);
    int getrad (Mat& im,int& i, int& j,int width, int height);
    int getrad1 (Mat& im,int& i, int& j,int width, int height);
    bool searchleft(Mat& im,int& i, int& j,int width, int height);
    int* checkcoderight (Mat& im,Mat& im1,int& i, int& j,int width, int height);
    bool checkcodeleft (Mat& im,Mat& im1,int& i, int& j,int width, int height,int d);
    bool checkcodeleft1 (Mat& im,Mat& im1,int& i, int& j,int width, int height,int d);
    void readcode(Mat& im,int& istart,int & jstart,int d);
    string code;

    };


   #endif // !defined(EA_FCDF0E51_9C9E_4b28_8C4A_8703EFEE38FC__INCLUDED_)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: 1. Fix your indentation. 2. Provide more useful contextual information. (Hint: Merely copy/pasting your header file does not quite cut it.)

Comment: This assertion fail can be caused by things like a double `delete` or similar invalid operations related to memory. You should check your code for this kind of errors.

Comment: i get this error only if i make the declaration of "string code " in thé header file .
if the code is in the function read code declared i get not this error